# How to make an ASP:Repeater control editable using C# or VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, repeater

I am following this tutorial to make a repeater control:
http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_repeater.asp

I have successfully gotten as far as the tutorial, but I would like to make it editable.

How could I get started?

Comment: @John, didn't mean to step on your toes. I guess we were editing at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.. http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/ajax-tutorials/using-repeater-to-edit-in-line-with-ajax-in-c/